# Cannot show data from Realtime Database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
  query: FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("groups").child(widget.groupChatId).child("chats").orderByChild("time"),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot, Animation<double> animation, int index){
    return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.value!['message']));
  },)
```

I am trying to show my messages in the chat but I am getting error on this line - `return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.value!['message']));` It is showing `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'.`

Can anyone guide me on this?  I have been having issues retrieving specific data from Realtime Database. Could anyone also guide me on how to do that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type returned from [`DataSnapshot.value`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot/value.html) is an `Object?`, which doesn't have an `[]` defined on it. If you are certain that you're getting back a map, you can cast it with:

```
Text((snapshot.value! as Map)['message'])
```

Comment: thank you Frank. Tried that method before, it didn't work.. got this error instead..  

`_CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast)`

Comment: So it looks like your `snapshot` is a string already, and doesn't have a `message` child property. So `Text(snapshot.value!)`?

Comment: Hi Frank, it didn't work out on my end. However, `Text((snapshot.value! as Map)['message'])` was the most helpful on other functions that I am working on. So I will mark this as answered. Appreciate it.